# Am I linearizing this non-linear system properly?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have the following system:

$$x'=x(1-x)-xy$$
$$y'=y(1-\frac{y}{x})$$

I am trying to linearize it, and from my understanding, if the equilibrium points are hyperbolic, that is, its eigenvalues all have a non-zero real part, I can drop the higher order terms. If I compute $DF_{X_0}$, I get:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1-2x-y & -x \\ \frac{y^2}{x^2} & 1-\frac{2y}{x} \end{pmatrix}$$

When I drop the higher order terms, I am left with:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1-2x-y & -x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Am I linearizing this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have misunderstood this, you should **not** drop higher order terms **in the Jacobian** like you are doing! What you should to is to substitute the equilibrium that you want to investigate into the Jacobian. That will give you a *constant* matrix containing the coefficients of the first-order terms in the Taylor expansion around that point, so the “dropping of terms” is automatically taken care of.